Asymptotic lower bound for a mixing time on a path graph
We are given a simple path graph $P$ of $n$ nodes. It is well known that the mixing time $t_{\mathrm{mix}}(\varepsilon)$ is equal to $O(n^2)$ for $n\to\infty$.

Question: How can we derive a tight lower bound for $t_{\mathrm{mix}}(\varepsilon)$ when $n\to\infty$? Can we prove that $t_{\mathrm{mix}}(\varepsilon)=\Omega(n^2\log(1/\varepsilon))$ for $n\to\infty$?
